# Change Datepicker format

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datepicker

I have this code

```
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });
```

And result is a date like this 23/12/16 but i need to get format 23-12-2016
How I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
     format: 'dd-mm-yyyy'
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here we go:

Try to reconstruct DateTime string as like this:

```
var dateObj = $("#datepicker").val();
var newDate = new Date(dateObj );
var formattedString = [newDate.Date(),newDate.Month()+1, newDate.getFullYear()].join("-");
alert(formattedString );
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass "dd-mm-yy" as dateFormat.

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy" })
```